# jquery remove then append and do something onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick, append

On document ready, I have an onclick function that changes css of some elements with a class=project. If I remove those elements with class=project because of another event using .remove() then append new elements using .append() with class=project because of a different event, shouldn't my onclick event which changes the css still work because the new elements have class=project?

It doesn't look like it is but is there a way around that?

Comment: Can you please post the code your referring to?

Comment: Probably you're using `click` instead of `on`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned about jQuery's .delegate and it does exactly want I want. I can remove and append all I want. I hope this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 2):

No you need to delegate or bind the new elements with the event handler again because they didnt' exist at the time of binding.

```
$('.project').on('click',function(){...}) // <-- elements must exist at time of binding

$('body').on('click','.project',function(){...}) // <-- event handler is attached to an ancestor element - which is body in this example
// the ancestor element will now listen to events from elements with class=project and handle the events as they bubble up
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.detach` instead of `.remove`.  However, it sounds like you want to use delegation.  At least:

```
$(document).on('click', '.project', function () {
```

Instead of using `document`, you should try to use a more specific selector like the parent of the container of the `.project` elements.